# IOS (10) disable state preservation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

When someone uses my app and presses the home button (enter background state), I want my app to re-launch (enter foreground state) in my initial view controller.

I thought it would be just some bool I needed to set in my **AppDelegate** but no luck there until now, scrolled through every method thinkable but no.

I tried this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial
to tell my app to get back to my initial view controller but no success.

I get the impression that you need to tell your app that it needs to restore into a previous state and it will not do this until you set it up right, but my app just preserves state and enters where you left off after using the home button.

Comment: State restoration allows an app to preserve its state when it is suspended so that if the app is then terminated and later re-launched it can be restored to the same state. When you press the home button that immediately suspends the app but does not necessarily terminate it (double tap home and swipe it out of the list of recent apps to ensure termination) switching back to the app later may therefore resume where you left off and not require state restoration at all.

Comment: Set the info.plist key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to true https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 this was the solution. couldn't have guessed it would be so simple. One think i'm sure of, I wouldn't have found this on my own, I was searching in a completely different direction. Thnx!